# css hover background loaded div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I had a main div which position is relative and inside that I laded 2 more div's which position is absolute, z index accordingly and inside each I loaded some images and give a hover effect to those images.

But the hover working only on highest z-index's div Even its parents background is transparent. My Css looks like

```
#main {
width:1000px;
height:500px;
position:relative;
} 

.gal_one {
width:800px;
height:400px;
position:absolute;
left:0;
top:0;
z-index:100;
}
.gal_one img {
margin-right:10px;
margin-bottom:10px;
float:left;
}
.gal_one img:hover {
border:1px solid #fff;      /* Working */
}

.gal_two {
width:800px;
height:400px;
position:absolute;
left:100px;
top:100px;
z-index:10;
}

.gal_two img {
margin-right:10px;
margin-bottom:10px;
float:left;
}
.gal_two img:hover {
border:1px solid #fff;      /* Not Working */
}

and the HTML part


<div id="main">
<div class="gal_one"> -- Loaded Images Here ---   </div>
<div class="gal_two"> -- Loaded Images Here ---   </div>
</div>
```

Any idea ? Please club

Comment: `float:left'` - error here, `'` should be `;`

Comment: @ramesh just updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have several issues:

1. your `#main` has height of `500px` while your divs `gal_one` and `gal_two` have height of `400px` which is total of `800px`
2. As your `.gal_one` and `.gal_two` is `absolute` positioned elements so you have to postion the `.gal_two` from the top to `400px` not `100px` due to this `.gal_two` is overlayed by `.gal_one`

then style it like this:

```
#main {
width:1000px;
height:500px; // <---- this is less than the total of the .gal_one + .gal_two = 800px;
position:relative;
} 

.gal_one {
width:800px;
height:400px;
position:absolute;
left:0;
top:0;
z-index:100;
}
.gal_one img {
margin-right:10px;
margin-bottom:10px;
float:left;
}
.gal_one img:hover {
border:1px solid #fff;      /* Working */
}

.gal_two {
width:800px;
height:400px;
position:absolute;
left:100px;
top:400px; // <----issue is here make 100px to 400px from top
z-index:10;
}

.gal_two img {
margin-right:10px;
margin-bottom:10px;
float:left;
}
.gal_two img:hover {
border:1px solid #fff;      /* Now this is working */
}
```

try this out in the fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/YSr94/**

Comment: No .. gallery_one over gallery_two

Comment: okay then you have to style your css according to your markup. I am updating the answer.

Comment: Hi Jay .. some misunderstanding between us .. I just updated the fiddle .. This is what I want actually .. Now I can hover gal_one's image but can't gal_two's image ... I would likes to make hover to both / all images.. Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you have settled width and height properties not right. Maybe one of Div blocks here come over second block and not letting it to show hover effect correctly. I actually tried the code posted here and found out that the problem is overlay matching. 
First remove the width and height of each div in CSS and then try reload the page.

```
.gal_one {
position:absolute;
left:0;
top:0;
z-index:100;
}


.gal_two {
position:absolute;
left:100px;
top:100px;
z-index:10;
}
```

Then correct ther width and height if the problem solved, cause you using absolute positioning and it may cause problems later.

Comment: tried it .. but still not working ... the gal_one overlaying gal_two ... not working the "hover" property of gal_two

Comment: it should work... what are the size of images you put in gal divs? cause i tested your code and it worked fine! in the chrome i mean